# Parallelize matlab code

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

In my Matlab script, I run an algorithm with a `for` loop in which, at each iteration, I need to do a gradient descent. All the gradient descent are independent. Here is the structure of my script :

```
for i=1:p

x=gradient_descent(x_init,grad_g,opts(i));

end
```

where `opts(i)` is a structure which contains variables necessary to the gradient descent. In this case, $p=145$. My script runs in $8$ seconds on my machine (without using any parallel trick). 
I have the impression that my script can be parallelized since each gradient descent in independent. When I un `matlabpool` on my computer, I can use up to 4 labs. Simultaneously, each lab could run a gradient descent and, instead of doing one gradient descent at a time, I would be able to do 4. But I do not know how I could parallelize my script. From what I have found on Internet, I could use the `batch` function, right ?

Comment: if you have the parallel toolbox you can use parfor instead of for. Maybe have a look here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/getting-started-with-parfor.html

Comment: Parfor won't work because of the way 'opts'  is used.

Comment: @jibounet Post a minimal example in which switching from for to parfor would cause Matlab to show the error that you get. (In your example, we are missing the definition of `opts`)

Comment: Did you check with setting only one core (`maxNumCompThreads`) for you system? If your performance drops by a factor of 4-ish, then it is already paralellized.

Comment: @zinjaai : I succeeded in using a parfor loop, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
parfor i=1:p
    x{i}=gradient_descent(x_init,grad_g,opts(i));
end
```

Comment: I adapted your answer to my script and I eventually got the parfor loop to work ! Everything works fine. Thanks !!